# Having trouble finding this 2x3 matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

I need to find a 2x3 matrix that does transformations from $\mathbb{R}^3$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$ given that it performs the following 3 transformations:
[image]

I know how to find 3x3 matrices by finding where $\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
0 \\
0
\end{pmatrix}$,  $\begin{pmatrix}
0 \\
1 \\
0
\end{pmatrix}$,  and $\begin{pmatrix}
0 \\
0 \\
1
\end{pmatrix}$ go geometrically but for some reason I'm blanking on how to do this with something like a 2x3. What am I missing?

Comment: The process is no different for a $2\times3$ matrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $$v_1 = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}, \quad v_2 = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}, \quad v_3 = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ -1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}.$$

Our **goal** is it to
 find a matrix $ A = \begin{pmatrix} a & b & c \\ d & e & f \end{pmatrix}$ such that $$Av_1 = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}, \quad Av_2 = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}, \quad Av_3 = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$$
as described in your notes.

Let us consider the **first equation**:

It is $Av_1 = \begin{pmatrix} a \\ d \end{pmatrix} \stackrel{!}{=} \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$, *so we obtain $a = 1, \, d = 0$*.

We do the same thing with the **second and third equation**:

$$Av_2 = \begin{pmatrix} b+c \\ e+f \end{pmatrix} \stackrel{!}{=} \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} , \quad Av_3 = \begin{pmatrix} -b+c \\ -e+f \end{pmatrix} \stackrel{!}{=} \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}.$$

**Now we want to find out what $b,c,e,f$ exactly are**.

*We start with $b$ and $c$*: 
The second and third equation give us $$\begin{align} b+c &= 0 \\ -b+c &= 0 \end{align}$$

which yields (by computing the linear system of equations) $b=c=0$.

*We do the same procedure with $e$ and $f$*:
The second and third equation give us $$\begin{align} e+f &= 1 \\ -e+f &= 0 \end{align}$$

which gives us $e = f = \frac{1}{2}$ this time.

So our **final result** is the matrix

$$ A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} \end{pmatrix}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Relative to the bases $\{\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\1\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix} 0\\-1\\1\end{pmatrix}\}$ 
 for $\mathbb R^3$and the standard basis for $\mathbb R^2$, the matrix is:   $\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1&0\end{pmatrix}$.

To get it relative to both standard bases, use the change of basis matrix: $\begin{pmatrix} 1&0&0\\0&1&-1\\0&1&1\end{pmatrix}^{-1}=\frac12\cdot\begin{pmatrix}2&0&0\\0&1&1\\0&1&1\end{pmatrix}$.

So, rel the standard bases, we get:  $\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1&0\end{pmatrix}\cdot\frac12 \begin{pmatrix}2&0&0\\0&1&1\\0&1&1\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\0&\frac12&\frac12\end{pmatrix}$.